# Suppress ‘focus theft’ of browser window

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

Is it possible to use Selenium whilst doing other work? When I run it the browser windows opened by Selenium always 'steal the focus' of my other windows. I am using C# and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround to this problem that I've been able to find is to run any long running test suites from inside of a VM so that it can steal all the focus it wants and it doesn't prevent me from continuing to do work.  Not sure if this is a feasible workaround for your circumstances or not though.